# Making checks before rsyncing external drive on OSX

Tags: macos, bash, rsync, uuid, mount

I have the following issue on OSX though I guess this could equally be filed under bash. I have several encrypted portable drives that I use to sync an offsite data store or as an on-the-go data store etc. I keep these updated using rsync with several options including --del and an includes file.
This is currently done very statically i.e.

```
rsync <options> --include-file=... /Volumes /Volumes/PortableData
```

where the includes file would read something like

```
+ /Abc/
+ /Def/
...
- *
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Check the correct drive is mounted and find its mount-point
2. Check that all the + /...../ entries are mounted under /Volumes
3. rsync

To achieve 1 I was intending to store the uuid of the drives in variables in my profile so that I could search for them and find the relevant mount point. A bash function in .bashrc that takes a uuid and returns a mount point. I have seen some web entries for achieving this.

2 I am a little more stuck on. What is the best way of retrieving only those entries that are both + and top level folder designations in the include files then iterating to check they are mounted and readable? Again, I'm thinking of trying to put some of this logic in functions for re-usability.

Is there a better way of achieving this? I have thought of CCC, but like the idea of scripting in bash and using rsync as it is a good way of getting to know the command line.

Answer (score 1):

rsync can call in a file that is a list of exclusions. 
I would write a script that dumped directories to text file that are NOT + and top level folder designations in the include files

You are going to want an exclusion to look like this:(you can use wildcards if it helps)

```
dirtoexlude1
dirtoexlude2
dirtoexlude
```

Then just direct an rsync to that exclusion file.
Your Rsync command will be something like this:

```
rsync -aP --exclude-from=rsyncexclusion.txt
```

a is for recursive essentially (with hand waving) and P is for verbose.

good luck.

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing a syntax example.